# Initializing an array with a loop and formula

Tags: java, arrays

Directions-

In the area for class instance variables:

- Declare an integer variable to hold the number of notes, set it to 13.
- Declare and allocate an array of GuitarString objects, of size 13. 
  Note: Make sure you remove the original instance variables (stringA and stringC).
- Declare an array of notes of type String, of size 13.
- Initialize the notes array with the following 13 values:
  "C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#","A","A#","B","H"
  In the main method:

Initialize the array of GuitarString in main for the entire octave.
You must use a loop, not thirteen separate statements.
Remember to allocate each GuitarString with new.
Use the following formula to calculate the frequency of each string:
double frequency = 440.0 * Math.pow(1.05956, index - 9);
p12.strings[index] = new GuitarString(frequency);

Here is the mapping for the index shown above:
        0 - middle C ("C")
        1 - C# above middle C ("C#")
        2 - D above middle C ("D")
        3 - D# above middle C ("D#")
        4 - E above middle C ("E")
        5 - F above middle C ("F")
        6 - F# above middle C ("F#")
        7 - G above middle C ("G")
        8 - G# above middle C ("G#")
        9 - A above middle C ("A")
        10 - A# above middle C ("A#")
        11 - B above middle C ("B")
        12 - high C ("H")

The above notes represent one octave of a piano from middle C to high C.

My Code-

```
public class P12 {



int numNotes = 13;
GuitarString[] GuitarString = new GuitarString[13];
public String[] strings = new String[]{"C", "C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#","A","A#","B","H"};



public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Instantiate object
    P12 p12 = new P12();



    for(int index = 0; index <= p12.numNotes; index++){
        double frequency = 440.0 * Math.pow(1.05956, index - 9);
        p12.strings[index] = new GuitarString(frequency);
    }
```

My question is how do I initialize the GuitarString array within the loop and using the given formula?

Comment: It appears that your instructor wants you to create a new object type of GuitarString, not to create an array of Strings

Comment: When I change it to make a new object I get: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from GuitarString to String"

Comment: Unrelated sidenote: I realize that your instructor is the one saying that the note H is equal to middle C, but H is actually equivalent to the note B: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%28musical_note%29. Just in case any musicians come across this post.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to your answer?

Comment: Changed some of the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class P12 {

int numNotes = 13;
public GuitarString[] gStrings = new GuitarString[13];
public String[] strings = new String[]{"C", "C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#","A","A#","B","H"};

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Instantiate object
    P12 p12 = new P12();

    for(int index = 0; index <= p12.numNotes; index++){
        double frequency = 440.0 * Math.pow(1.05956, index - 9);
        p12.strings[index] = new p12.GuitarString(frequency);
    }
}

private class GuitarString {

    double freq;

    GuitarString(double frequency) {
        freq = frequency;
    }

}
```